# Where does the Cavil copy come from in the Temple of Five (S03E12, Rapture)

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In Season 3 episode 12 of BSG, D'Anna and Baltar go down to the planet in a raider (which is part of the group of raiders that cause Galactica to begin the process of launching nukes, all of which turn back except the one containing D'Anna and Baltar). When they are on the planet you only see Baltar and D'Anna (where Baltar reassures D'Anna to see the Final Five).

Then as they enter the temple, suddenly there is a Cavil copy, where did he come from?

Answer (score 1):

A cavil copy rode down to the surface with D'anna and balter in the raider. It was mentioned that the cavil copy's where not sure if d'anna was just dreaming or really could see the final 5 in her dreams.

Either way, the cavil's wanted to box the d'anna's just for mentioning the final 5, which was a forbidden subject in the cylon world, because of what the cavil's did to the final 5 just before the attack on the colonies.

Comment: Difficult to understand.  Would probably help if it wasn't one long sentence.